# Writting variables in math format in matplotlib label

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

I have a list of variables that are Greek letters (56 variables so too many to do it per Hand). I would like to write those Greek letters in a matplotlib xlabel that it shows something like this in the xlabel:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
my_variable_list = ['\theta_m','\Omega_b h**2',..........,'log(A)']
plt.xlabel(r' $%s$ ' % my_variable_list[1])
```

but this doesn't work... It shows:

[image]

Does someone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: The error is telling you that `%i` requires a number in formatting, not a string, this has nothing to do with the math mode or the actual plotting.

Comment: try `%s` instead of `%i`

Comment: it's working with %s i.e. doesn't return an error but doesn't show the greek letter in math mode...

Comment: I have updated my topic with %s, thank you

Comment: @Apinorr that's weird, it's working for me, can you share more code? (the full plot)

Comment: I forgot the dollar sign on each side ^^ it's working now thanks a lot !!!

Comment: No problem :D . Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working for me with `%s`, if `'\theta'` didnt work use `'\\theta'`.

[image]